# module and subdomain for YII framework

Tags: module, yii, subdomain

I am using YII framework at one of my project and I am facing problem with Parameterizing Host Names, I have a module "ADMIN" and I want to display this as a subdomain within my domain, so I am setting rules like the following way from the protected/config/main.php:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            'http://admin.moresoccerfun.com/login' => 'admin/default/index',
        ),
    ),
```

But when I am running the page: www.admin.moresoccerfun.com/login from the browser, it is showing "SERVER NOT FOUND". Please help me out from this problem.

Thanks and looking for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Yii can handle that request, your server needs to be properly configured.
Basically, you need to edit your DNS entries and your Apache config.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html
http://content.websitegear.com/article/subdomain_setup.htm

Comment: OK thank you very much for your reply, how can I change the the VirtualHost of my server? means I have the Cpanel access of the server, in which process can I change this?

Comment: First google result: http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-add-a-new-virtual-host-using-cpanel-1662.html